# CodeIgniter, Is it possible to use an helper within a custom helper?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writting my custom helper. I tried to use the language helper:

```
$this->lang->line('site_title')
```

I get an error :

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
C:\Users\guest\Wamp\www\codeIgniter\application\helpers\blog_helper.php on line 15
```

Comment: Post the relevant sections of the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to call methods from the CodeIgniter super object within a helper (or a custom library) you'll need to use the `get_instance()` function. This will reference the CodeIgniter super object to the variable $ci - so you can call the CodeIgniter methods by using `$ci` rather than `$this`:

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$site_title = $ci->lang->line('site_title');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use the language helper:

$site_title = lang('site_title');

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/language_helper.html

That is assuming the helper before this point. Otherwise just do as above.