# CodeIgniter - Custom help doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to learn how to better use the Codeigniter framework for my needs. Today I'm encountering an issue with the creation of an Helper. I kindly ask you to support me, just to understand how I can develop them.

I've created a checkurl_helper.php under applications/helper/. The content of the file is the following:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    /* Function to check page name for urls*/
    function activecheck($page_name) {
        $check_current_name = $this->uri->segment(1);
        if ($page_name == $check_current_name) {
            echo "active";
        }  
   };

// echo active_check('page_name');
```

I've imported the helper in my controller -> /application/controllers/Pages.php

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }   

        public function about() {

            $data['title'] = ucfirst("about");

            //load custom helper 
            $this->load->helper('checkurl');

            if (!$this->user->loggedin) {
                $this->load->view('templates/header_no_login', $data);
            } else {    
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            }
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebarmenu_main');
            $this->load->view('pages/'.$data['title'].'.php');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
}
```

Now, on my template file "sidebarmenu_main" I've called the function of the helper in the following way:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
   <li class="header">FSG MENU</li>
   <li class="<?php active_check('about'); ?>"><a href="/about"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>About</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

So, if I'm in the "localhost/about" page, the Helper should be able to retrieve the word "about" from the url. So, through the command "active_check('about'), the script should give the output "active". I need the "active" output to highlight the voice in the menu box to say to the user that he is navigating in the "about" page.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do.

The issue, in any case, is that the calling of the function in the "sidebarmenu_main" brakes all the page and doesn't give any output. I've checked if the $this->uri->segment(1) works and there's no issue.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Did you turn on error reporting? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I've activated the "Development" environment in CodeIgniter. This is the error: "A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Using $this when not in object context

Filename: helpers/checkurl_helper.php

Line Number: 5

Backtrace:"

Answer (score 1):

Your function name is

```
function activecheck($page_name)
```

and you are calling inside of view

```
active_check('about');
```

add _ to function

Comment: You are right, there was a mistake but the issue is still there. The helper is not working.

Comment: maybe because you added `$this->load->view('pages/'.$data['title'].'.php');` .php at the end? and if you didn't make a route for about then your url will be `url.com/pages/about` so you need uri segment 2

Comment: mmm, no Marko. I've tested the "$this->uri->segment(1)" and it gives me "about" so it works. The error in CodeIgniter is the following: "A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error Message: Using $this when not in object context Filename: helpers/checkurl_helper.php Line Number: 5 Backtrace:"

Comment: did you autoload url helper inside of config file ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852706/codeigniter-is-it-possible-to-use-an-helper-within-a-custom-helper check this

Comment: `$ci =& get_instance();
$check_current_name = $ci->uri->segment(1);`

It would look like this

Comment: Exactly Marko. The missing point was the "$ci =& get_instance(); $check_current_name = $ci->uri->segment(1);". Thanks a lot!!!